# Want to animate a fade-In the H1 innerText with the class="body-title" each time the innertext changes

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

So i have the following problem:

The innerText changes each time i click and the H1 displays the value of actualSite array

I can't manage to load the animation fade-in each time the innerText changes.

My question is what do i need to change or add to trigger the fade-in animation each time the innertext changes?

this is my code:

**main.component.html:**

```html
<div class="screen"[@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <div class="header d-flex">
    <div class="header-left"></div>
    <div class="header-middle header-btn" (click)="btnSlide(-1)" [attr.disabled]="isButtonDisabled(currentIndex - 1)">
      <div class="header-middle-content">
        <div class="header-middle-icon"><fa-icon  [icon]="faSortUp"></fa-icon></div>
        <h1 class="header-middle-text">{{actualSite[currentIndex -1]}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right header-btn d-flex justify-content-center"><h1 class="header-right-content align-self-end">Settings</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body-header">
    <h1 class="body-title" [@fadeIn]="'true'">
      {{ actualSite[currentIndex] | uppercase }}
    </h1>
    <div class="body-header-body align-self-center d-flex justify-content-end">
      <h1 class="body-header-title align-self-center">
        {{Weather?.location}}
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body-screen">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="body-footer">
    <div class="body-footer-down d-flex justify-content-between">
      <h2 class="body-footer-brand align-self-center">supported by OpenWeather</h2>
      <h2 class="body-footer-date align-self-center">As of
        {{ Weather?.time | date: 'h:mm a'}},
        {{ Weather?.day | date: 'dd/MM'}}
        </h2>
      <div class="body-footer-underline"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer d-flex">
    <div class="footer-left footer-btn" (click)="btnstart()">
      <h1 class="footer-left-content align-self-start">Wii Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-middle footer-btn" (click)="btnSlide(1)" [attr.disabled]="isButtonDisabled(currentIndex + 1)">
      <div class="footer-middle-content">
        <fa-icon class="footer-middle-icon" [icon]="faSortDown"></fa-icon>
        <h1 class="footer-middle-text">{{actualSite[currentIndex +1]}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right footer-btn">
    <h1 class="footer-right-content align-self-start">Globe</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { fadeInAnimation }  from 'src/app/shares/animation/fade-in.animation';






@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
  animations:[slider,fadeInAnimation]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  faSortUp = faSortUp;
  faSortDown = faSortDown;

  public Current : Current | undefined;
  public Today : Today | undefined;
  public Tomorrow : Tomorrow | undefined;
  public Weather : Weather | undefined;
  public actualSite: string[] = ['UV-Index','Current','Today','Tomorrow','5-Day Forecast'];
  public urlTitle : string | undefined = '';
  public currentIndex : number = 1;



  constructor(private readonly weatherService : WeatherService,
              private readonly iconService : IconService,
              private readonly sessionDataService : SessionDataService,
              private readonly router : Router
              )
              {}

  public prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }

  public btnstart(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/start');
  }

  public btnSlide(increment: number){
    this.urlTitle = this.router.url.split('/').pop();
    const newIndex = this.currentIndex + increment;
    if (newIndex >= 1 && newIndex < this.actualSite.length) {
      this.currentIndex = newIndex;
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`main/${this.actualSite[newIndex]}`);

      switch(this.actualSite[newIndex]){
        case'Current':
        this.Weather = this.Current;
          return
        case 'Today':
          this.Weather = this.Today;
          this.Weather!.wind.speed = this.Today!.wind.gust
          return
        case 'Tomorrow':
          this.Weather = this.Tomorrow;
          return
      }
    }
  }


  isButtonDisabled(index: number) {
    return index === 1 || index === this.actualSite.length - 1;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.urlTitle = this.router.url.split('/').pop();

    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{
        this.weatherService.setWeather(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude,'metric','');
        this.weatherService.getCurrentWeather$()
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((data) =>{
          this.Current = {...data[0]};
          this.Current!.icon = this.iconService.getIcon(this.Current!.description);
          this.sessionDataService.outputCurrent(this.Current);
          this.Today = {...data[1]};
          this.Today!.icon = this.iconService.getIcon(this.Today!.description);
          this.sessionDataService.outputToday(this.Today);

          switch(this.urlTitle){
            case'Current':
              this.Weather = this.Current;
              this.currentIndex = 1;
              return
            case 'Today':
              this.Weather = this.Today;
              this.currentIndex = 2;
              return
          }
        });
        this.weatherService.getWeekWeather$()
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((data) =>{
          this.Tomorrow = {...data};
          this.Tomorrow!.icon = this.iconService.getIcon(this.Tomorrow!.description);
          this.sessionDataService.outputTomorrow(this.Tomorrow);
          switch(this.urlTitle){
            case'Tomorrow':
              this.Weather = this.Tomorrow;
              this.currentIndex = 3;
              return
            case '5-Day Forecast':
              this.Weather = this.Tomorrow;
              this.currentIndex = 4;
              return
          }
        });
      });
    };
  }

}
```

**fade-in.animation.ts**

```
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

export const fadeInAnimation = trigger('fadeIn', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
]);
```